# How to configure Cygnus to save in mysql

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying to configure Cygnus in order to persist Orion context data in a MySQL database. I have installed phpmyadmin, and I'm trying to use this database to save the data. The whole workflow is the following one: Orion recives some data, then it is sent to Cygnus, and finally Cygnus sends it to the SQL db.

This is my configuration:

```
# OrionMySQLSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs 
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = x.y.z.w
# the port where the MySQL server listens for incomming connections
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
# a valid user in the MySQL server
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = xxxxxxxxxxxx
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
```

Comment: Is it your real configuration? I mean, it seems you are missing some configuration parameters, such as the mysqh host and the password.

Comment: In addition, AFAIK `phpmyadmin` is just a tool for administrating MySQL on top of Http, but it is not a MySQL database... I think you will need to install MySQL itself.

Comment: if I have installed lamp, and I need to keep in Cygnus configure the database that is installed with lamp . Ip localhost guess it will be the username and password of my database . but there qeu configure something else?

Answer (score 1):

A correct configuration file look like this:

```
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = localhost 
# the port where the MySQL server listes for incomming connections
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
# a valid user in the MySQL server
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = YOURUSERNAME
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = YOURPASSWORD
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
```

You should also have a look at the iptables and open the MySQL port (default port is 3306)

For testing purposes you can run contextbroker in your terminal (don't forget to stop the service before) with

```
contextBroker -port 1026
```

and cygnus in other terminal (don't forget to stop the service before) with

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/YOURAGENT.CONF -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

(take care to change "YOURAGENT.CONF" and "cygnusagent" if you changed the name of the agent)

so you could see the output in realtime.

The database tables are not created automatically in column mode. So you would have to create the tables.

The columns look like :
recvTime - datetime ,
field1 ,
field2
....
field1_md - varchar ,
field2_md - varchar
....

If you change

`cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column`

to

```
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row
```

tables are created automatically, but I prefer the column way to save and handle data.

I hope this helps you.